# Capture of elk probabilities

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**Question:**
Elk dwell in a certain forest. There are $N$ elk, of which a simple random sample of size $n$ are captured and tagged (“simple random sample" means that all $\binom{N}{n}$ sets of elk $n$ are equally likely). The captured elk are returned to the population, and then a new sample is drawn, this time with size $m$. What is the probability that exactly $k$ of the $m$ elk in the new sample were previously tagged? (Assume that an elk that was captured before doesn’t become more or less likely to be captured again.)

I simply cannot wrap my head around this. Spent around an afternoon trying to understand, nothing.

I'm trying to put it in terms that I might undersand it. Can someone tell me if my explanation of the result is correct and help me complete it.

The correct answer is $\frac{\binom{n}{k}.\binom{N-n}{m-k}}{\binom{N}{m}}$

Breaking down the different expressions, I get:

- $\binom{n}{k}$ : out of the number of elks tagged on the first capture ($n$), how many of them were captured the second time around ($k$).

*So this is the number of elks that were captured both in the first and second capture.*

- $N - n$: total number of elks - the number of elks captured during the first capture.

*This is the total number of elks that were NOT captured during the first capture*

- $m - k$: number of elks in the second capture - the number of elks in the second capture that were ALSO in the first capture.

*This is the number of elks in the second capture that WEREN'T in the first capture*

- $\binom{N-n}{m-k}$: from the total number of elks that were NOT captured during the first capture, choose the number of elks in the second capture that weren't in the first capture.

*This is equivalent to choosing, from elks that didn't get captured the first time, picking groups of the number of elks that were only in the second capture and not the first*. I don't understand what that means logically.

- $\binom{n}{k}.\binom{N-n}{m-k}$: We calculate the number of ways in which we pick the number of elks captured in the first AND second capture - AND - the number of ways in which we can pick elks that were captured ONLY the second time in the group of elks that didn't get captured the first time.

The fraction makes sense since we are dividing by the sample space to find the probability.

I'm not sure that the above is correct, even if it is correct, I still massively lack the intuition as to what any of it means in relation to answering the question. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I think that your analysis is very close.  I offer a somewhat different intuition.  The denominator of $~\displaystyle \binom{N}{m}~$ represents the total number of equally likely ways of selecting the $~m~$ elk in the second sampling.

Let

- $A~$ denote the subset of elk that were chosen in the first sampling. 
  Then $~|A| = n.~$
- $B~$ denote the subset of elk that were not chosen in the first sampling. 
  Then $~|B| = N-n.$

An elk in the second sampling will have been previously tagged if and only if it came from subset $~A,~$ rather than subset $~B.~$

In order for there to be exactly $~k~$ such elk, you must have that exactly $~k~$ of the $~m~$ elk came from subset $~A,~$ and $~(m-k)~$ of the $~m~$ elk came from subset $~B.~$

Since $~|A| = n,~$ the number of ways of selecting $~k~$ elk from subset $~A,~$ sampling without replacement, where order of selection is irrelevant is $~\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}.~$

Since $~|B| = N-n,~$ the number of ways of selecting $~(m-k)~$ elk from subset $~B,~$ sampling without replacement, where order of selection is irrelevant is $~\displaystyle \binom{N-n}{m-k}.~$

The choice of the $~k~$ elk from subset $~A~$ are *independent* of the choice of the $~(m-k)~$ elk from subset $~B.~$ That is, regardless of which $~k~$ elk are chosen from subset $~A,~$ there will still be exactly $~\displaystyle \binom{N-n}{m-k}~$ equally likely ways of selecting the $~(m-k)~$ elk from subset $~B.$

Therefore, the number of equally likely ways that (in the second sampling) $~k~$ elk came from subset $~A,~$ and $~(m-k)~$ elk came from subset $~B~$ is

$$\binom{n}{k} \times \binom{N-n}{m-k}.$$